# In VB.NET, how do you get a list of all users in the current Windows machine?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net

In VB.NET, how do you get a list of all users in the current Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the registry which requires a little bit of parsing but hey it works.  Here is some code:

**C#**

```
 RegistryKey userskey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList");
        foreach (string keyname in userskey.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
                using (RegistryKey key = userskey.OpenSubKey(keyname))
                {
                    string userpath = (string)key.GetValue("ProfileImagePath");
                    string username = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(userpath);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", username);
                }
        }
```

**VB**

```
Dim userskey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList")
For Each keyname As String In userskey.GetSubKeyNames()
    Using key As RegistryKey = userskey.OpenSubKey(keyname)
        Dim userpath As String = DirectCast(key.GetValue("ProfileImagePath"), String)
        Dim username As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(userpath)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", username)
    End Using
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an improved version of [Nathan W's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485341/in-vb-net-how-do-you-get-a-list-of-all-users-in-the-current-windows-machine#485754) answer:

```
Function GetUsers() As List(Of String)
    Dim ret As New List(Of String)
    Dim userskey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList")
    For Each keyname As String In userskey.GetSubKeyNames()
        Using key As RegistryKey = userskey.OpenSubKey(keyname)
            Dim userpath As String = DirectCast(key.GetValue("ProfileImagePath"), String)
            Dim username As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(userpath)
            'Console.WriteLine("{0}", username)
            ret.Add(username)
        End Using
    Next
    If Not ret.Contains("Guest") Then ret.Add("Guest")
    ret.Sort()

    Return ret
End Function
```

This function returns a list of all users on the current domain/machine from the registry. For his answer, it doesn't recognize the Guest account on my system. Don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 11 true works today:

```
Private Function GetLocalUsers() As List(Of String)
    Dim OpenCMD
    OpenCMD = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    OpenCMD.run("cmd /C wmic useraccount list full | clip", 0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    Dim result As String = Clipboard.GetText()
    Dim lines() As String = result.Split({vbCrLf, vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    For Each linea As String In lines
        If Mid(linea, 1, 5) = "Name=" Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(Mid(linea, 6, linea.Length))
        End If
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function
```